# function onEdit() runs only partially

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a very frustrating problem on my hands and I turn to you for help once more. I had the `onEdit()` function below which, together with the auxiliary functions, worked fine.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();

  //Check if the sheet is a JOb sheet and the cell us the status cell
  if ( activeSheet.getName().indexOf("Job ID") != -1 && activeCell.getRow() == 4 && activeCell.getColumn() == 15 ) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Active Jobs');
    var jobRowNumber = findJobIdRow();
    var sourceCell = activeSheet.getRange(4,15);
    sourceCell.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(jobRowNumber,16));
  }

  if (activeSheet.getName().indexOf("Job ID") != -1 && activeCell.getRow() == 2 && activeCell.getColumn() == 15){
    var switchValue = activeCell.getValue();
    switch (switchValue){
      case "On hold (i)":
      case "On hold (ii)":
      case "On hold (iii)":
      case "To be assigned":
        //Write date to active jobs sheet
        addDateToActive("TBC");
        break;
      case "In progress":
        var newDate = Browser.inputBox("Please enter report out date, example 18-Aug-2017");
        addDateToActive(newDate);
        break;
      //default:
        //Browser.msgBox("GOTHERE");
    }
  }
}

function findJobIdRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var jobID = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1).getValue();
  var column = ss.getSheetByName('Active Jobs').getRange(2,1,ss.getSheetByName('Active Jobs').getMaxRows()-2,1);
  var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
  for(var ct = 0; ct < values.length-1; ct++){
    if(values[ct][0] == jobID){
      var ct = ct+2;
      break;
    }
  }
  return ct;
}

function addDateToActive(input){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
  var jobid = activeSheet.getRange(2,1).getValue().toString();
  var activeJobSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Active Jobs");
  var activeJobs = activeJobSheet.getRange(1,1,activeJobSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  activeJobs = ColumnToArray(activeJobs);
  var jobrow = activeJobs.indexOf(jobid)+1;
  if (jobrow == -1){
    Browser.msgBox("Job Id not preent on Active Jobs sheet");
  }else{
    activeJobSheet.getRange(jobrow,15).setValue(input);
  }
}
```

Then I included some code in this script which was supposed to send out some e-mails to people if some dates were approaching today's date. There were some problems with that code because of authorization requirement so I moved it into it's own separate function and came back to the original script that is posted above. Now the problem I am facing is, although this script works fine if ran from the script editor, manually run from a drawing button in the spreadsheet, or is ran by a on edit trigger I set up from the "Current project triggers" menu, it will not do the entire script if the script is triggered by the onEdit() function name. It does the first bit where it copies the content of a cell across but not the second bit with the case switch.

The obvious fix would be to just set up the trigger from the "Current project triggers" but this onEdit detection needs to apply to anyone in my team that edits this sheet. If I set it up like that it will work for me but no one else from my team.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The function name `onEdit` is a *reserved* function name.  When the spreadsheet is edited (an event), Apps Script looks for a function named `onEdit` and if it exists, it runs it.  But `onEdit` is a *simple* trigger, it won't execute any code that requires the user to authorize permission.  Change the name of the `onEdit` function to something else, and then update the installed trigger setting for the function name.  The only way your function will run for people you share the Sheet with, is if they have Edit permissions to the Sheet file.

Comment: Hi Sandy ! Thank you for the reply. But in this case the onEdit function exists and it works if ran manually. This worked in the past and what I am asking it to do now doesn't require any special permission, it's just editing cells in the spreadhseet the user has open. Any trigger that I set up from the "Current project triggers" will not be communicated to other users. I know because I tried it.

Comment: There is a new permission requirement to display a sidebar or dialog.  I don't know if it also extends to a browser message or input box.  Try removing the browser message and input box, and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @SandyGood do you have a reference to the new permission requirement to display and sidebar or dialog.

Comment: @Cooper  There is no documentation for this new permission as far as I know.  I only know about it from experience.

Comment: @SandyGood Yeh I had similar experiences recently but I couldn't find  anything in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the trigger via the function name onEdit() proving tricky I wrote this bit of code and attached it to a drawing in the sheet. Then instructed all the users to click it which set up the trigger for them. This solved the problem and the trigger works fine now.

```
function triggerSetUp(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("enforcer").forSpreadsheet(sheet).onEdit().create();
}
```